# A combinatorial identity: $ \sum_{k=m}^n \frac{\binom{1/2}{k-m}}{k \binom{-1/2}{k}}=\frac{\binom{-1/2}{n-m}}{m \binom{-1/2}{n}} $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $m,n$ be two positive integer, $n>m$. I have trouble proving that
$$
\sum_{k=m}^n \frac{\binom{1/2}{k-m}}{k \binom{-1/2}{k}}=\frac{\binom{-1/2}{n-m}}{m \binom{-1/2}{n}}
$$
Any suggestions, please? Thank you very much.

Comment: Use $\binom{x}{k}=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}$ and simplify.

Comment: Looks amusing. What's the source?

Comment: @GrigoryM, my teacher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a summand that does not depend on $n$ and you have a conjecture for general $n$ (which is clearly true for $m=n$), so it just remains to check the induction step:

$$\frac{\binom{-1/2}{n-m}}{m \binom{-1/2}{n}}+\frac{\binom{1/2}{n-m+1}}{(n+1) \binom{-1/2}{n+1}}=\frac{\binom{-1/2}{n-m+1}}{m \binom{-1/2}{n+1}},$$

which reduces to a polynomial identity after you cancel all common factors.